# Export contacts from Facebook instant forms through cURL not works

Tags: facebook, curl

I'm using this cURL command line to download contacts in a CSV file:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&type=form&from_date=1672531200&to_date=1699401599"
```

where "`xxxxxxxxxxxxx`" is the ID of instant form. However it doesn't work because it needs to first log in to the Facebook page where the instant form resides.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: You will either have to set up an environment that allows you to simulate a user login (would not recommend - high risk of getting the involved accounts blocked, if Facebook detects anything "suspicious"), or fetch your necessary data via API instead, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/